# Go from JSP to Servlet, then come back to same JSP and the fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I need to go from my JSP to my Servlet and then come back to the same JSP. The problem is that when i come back all my text fields are empty.

How do i solve this? Notes:

1. The form has `method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'`.
2. I'm using buttons to submit. They are normal buttons that execute a javascript function onclick, this function validates the text fields and if everything is ok then it calls to the `submit()` function and submits the form.
3. The come back from the servlet is being done with this code:

   ```
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/altaPerfil.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);
   ```

**Additional info:**

My JSP page is similar to this one: https://www.taringa.net/registro. 
It has one form, inside the form there are 7 text fields, 3 select fields for the date(exactly like in that page), an upload field to upload an image, a radioButton with two fields and 3 buttons.
One of the buttons is used to validate the nick and email fields(if the nick or mail are already taken it returns false, otherwise returns true, this is done in the servlet because we try to keep the logic separated from the presentation). 
The second button is used to upload the image.
The third button is used to send all the form(all the text fields and the date).
The first two buttons must go to the servlet and come back to the JSP...
**Example code:** 
**(JSP)**

```
<form action="altaPerfilServlet" 
      name = "frmValidar" 
      method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >

    Nick:
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="nick" 
           id="nick" onkeypress="deshabilita()" 
           value="${requestScope.nick}" />

<input type=button name="botonValidar" 
           id="botonValidar" value="Validar datos" 
           onclick="validarNick()" />
<!--Note: the javascript validarNick() verifies the nick field and if it is -->
<!--not empty then it calls frmValidar.submit()-->
```

**(Servlet)**

```
  FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

  List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
  Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();

  <!--here i process all the FileItems and obtain their values-->
  <!--then i talk to a java app (which acts as a server, providing -->
  <!--the data and a series of classes) and obtain a boolean value(esValido)-->
  <!--that tells me if the nick is available(true) or taken(false)-->

  <!--finally: -->

  request.setAttribute("esValido", esValido);<!-- saving the boolean -->

  String nick=request.getParameter("nick");
  request.setAttribute("nick", nick);
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/altaPerfil.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Show us the JSP code that renders the form. Unless you're setting the input values, or using a forms framework/library, the fields won't magically repopulate.

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand what you want, the term "render" is confusing me(i don't speak english very well, sorry).
If you want the code that is in the form, that won't be possible since it's 200 lines aproximately.

Comment: Show us a small, representative example of what the form looks like in the JSP.

Comment: Edited the question, if you expected code just tell me and i will add an example.

Comment: Matt was saying that if you want there to be values in the form they must be set by you--they won't populate themselves.

Comment: That's what i'm asking for... i have no idea on how to repopulate them, I tried saving the text-fields values in the request(setting them as attributes) and then using scriptlets in each text field to set the values but it's giving me a headache and i'm not getting results. How can I repopulate the text fields?

Answer (score 1):

Read the `<input>` data from `request` in `doPost` method and push/bind `<input>` data into request scope.

sample.jsp

---

```
<form method="post" action="servlet_url">
  No   : <input type="text" name="no" value="${requestScope.no}"/>
  Name : <input type="text" name="name" value="${requestScope.name}"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and code in `doPost`,

```
String no=request.getParameter("no");
String name=request.getParameter("name");

//other statements

request.setAttribute("no",no);
request.setAttribute("name",name);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sample.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I added some code to my question, maybe things are more clear now.
Regarding your answer: with your code nothing happens with the field nick, when i come back from the servlet the field is empty. Anyway it is curious that if I do the same thing using the boolean value from my example(called esValido) instead of the String nick, then when i come back from the servlet the text field nick has the value true or false(depending on the value of the boolean). So it's apparently working but only with my boolean attribute, not with my String attributes...

Comment: So, basically: your trick worked only with a boolean(i can repopulate my textfields with a boolean value brought into the request from the servlet), but it is not working with Strings... When i try with a String nothing happens, the text field is empty when i come back from the servlet...

Comment: Now working, the problem was that i was using request.getAttribute() for the nick and it doesn't work(not sure why).
Thanks for the tip!!